Use blow-up to extend a morphism
I've learnt about blow-ups in a basic algebraic geometry course which only deals with varieties (integral, finite type, separated). It looks a bit different from the usual definition using schemes.

Let $X, Y$ be varieties over $k$ and $U\subset X$ is open. Assume $Y$ to be complete. Consider a morphism $f:U\to Y$ with graph $\Gamma_f\subset U\times Y\subset X\times Y$. Define $\text{Bl}_f(X)$ to be the closure of $\Gamma_f$ in $X\times Y$.

Projection induces $\pi:\text{Bl}_f(X)\to X$ and $\tilde{f}:\text{Bl}_f(X)\to Y$. Assume $Y$ is complete. Then we have the following properties

$\pi$ is an surjection and it induces an isomorphism $\pi^{-1}(U)\to U$.
$\tilde{f}=f\cdot\pi$ on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ so $\tilde{f}$ extends $f$ to $\text{Bl}_f(X)$.
Suppose we have a variety $X'$ with two morphisms $\pi':X'\to X$ and $f':X'\to Y$ satisfying the two properties above. Then there exists uniquely $\tau:X'\to \text{Bl}_f(X)$ such that $f'=\tilde{f}\cdot \tau$ and $(\pi')^{-1}(U)\cong \pi^{-1}(U)$ via $\tau$.

Thus $\text{Bl}_f(X)$ is in some sense the “smallest” modification of $X$ on which $f$ extends.
However, the usual definition of blow-ups involves effective divisors etc. and there is nothing like how a morphism extends. So I wonder if there is a scheme-theoretic version of this. Is this some generalization of the usual blow-ups?

This is a very interesting question! I'm quite certain, though a counter-example didn't come by easily so far, that it's not a plain special case of the usual blow up, for there's no reason for $\pi$ to be projective, e.g.

Does your reference go into the details to which extent this blow up depends on $U$?

@Ben Indeed, this does recover the usual blow-up sometimes, but is more general since it might not be projective.

@Ben Unfortunately, no. This is just an exercise from the lecture.

I am still intrigued by this question. Unfortunately, what I have to add so far is rather boring: Strictly speaking, we can recover the usual (non-trivial) blow up (of varieties), supposing it's already known to exist, as it is a special case of the following
Observation: If $g\colon Y\to X$ is a surjective morphism of integral, proper varieties which is an isomorphism over a dense open $U\subset X$, then denoting $f\colon U\to Y$ the inverse of $g$, we have $\mathop{Bl}_f(X)=Y$ with $\tilde f=\mathop{id}_Y$ and $\pi=g$.
The proof is a series of tautologies, it's really nothing deep. Moreover, saying that, therefore, the usual blow up is a special case of the one described in the OP is rather unsatisfactory, for this does not at all show why this version of the blow up satisfies the universal property of the usual blow up when used like this.
Proof. By assumption , $\pi=g$ is surjective, an isomorphism over $U$ and $f\circ \pi = f\circ g$ is the identity over $U$, hence $f\circ\pi=\tilde f$ over $U$. It remains to show that if $X\xleftarrow{\pi'} X'\xrightarrow{f'}Y$ satisfies the same properties, then there exists a unique morphism $\tau\colon X'\to Y$ satisfying $f'=\tilde f\circ \tau$ and which restricts to an isomorphism $\pi'^{-1}(U)\to \pi^{-1}(U)$.
Uniqueness is trivial, for $\tilde f=\mathop{id}_Y$ and so $\tau=f'$. It remains to show that $\tau=f'$ does indeed restrict to an isomorphism $\pi'^{-1}(U)\to \pi^{-1}(U)$. But by assumption, $\tau=f'$ agrees with $f\circ\pi'$ on $\pi'^{-1}(U)$ and by assumption, $\pi'$ restricts to an isomorphism $\pi'^{-1}(U)\to U$ and $f$ is also assumed to be an isomorphism $U\to f(U)=g^{-1}(U)=\pi^{-1}(U)$. This proves the observation.
As for (more or less) general schemes, I suspect that if $U$ is scheme-theoretically dense in $X$, the scheme-theoretic image of the graph morphism $U\to X\times Y$ with its projections onto $X$ and $Y$, respectively, will satisfy similar conditions under rather mild assumptions on the schemes. It might be worthwhile to replace the condition that the unique morphism $\tau$ as in the OP's setup induces an isomorphism over $U$ to the global (and as far as I can see over integral varieties equivalent) condition that $\pi\circ \tau=\pi'$. But this is just a bold claim I cannot substantiate since I haven't looked into it deeply enough.

I think we need separatedness to show $\pi$ induces an isomorphism over U and completeness to show the surjectivity of $\pi$. However, the usual blow-up doesn't assume separatedness.

I'm not sure if I can follow. Are you trying to do the same for schemes and then recover the scheme-theoretical blow up? Or do you think something is wrong with my argument (where I intentionally restricted myself to varieties). Surely this stuff is going to fail if things fail to be separated.

I think for general schemes, what should be done is add a section $U\to X'$ to the datum for the universal property and require that it shall be dominant. I think I have a proof that the closure of the graph of $f$ does the job under the assumption that $Y$ is proper and $U\subset X$ is retro-compact and dense and $f$ is quasi-compact. (Without properness, I don't see how you're ever supposed to get $\pi$ to be surjective and I need the maps to be quasi-compact so that the images behave nicely.) But I still don't see the point of calling this a blow up.

I just want to add a remark. I think your new comment could be a good way to solve the problem of surjectivity.
